# Cual es la manera mas facil de generar una vista que me muestre los encabezado y los detalles ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quisiera obtener los detalles de un encabezado ya los tengo todos relacionados solo me falta mostrarlos en la misma vista, intente añadirlo pero me dice `undefined method cod_prod for nil:NilClass`

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
<strong>Numero oc:</strong>
<%= @encabezado.numero_oc %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Tipo oc:</strong>
<%= @encabezado.tipo_oc %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Fecha g:</strong>
<%= @encabezado.fecha_g %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Fecha en:</strong>
<%= @encabezado.fecha_en %>
</p>
<p>
<strong>Cod prod:</strong>
<%= @detalle.cod_prod %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Numero item:</strong>
<%= @detalle.numero_item %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Descrip:</strong>
<%= @detalle.descrip %>
</p>
```

Si hay alguna manera mas simple seria genial quiero ya terminar este proyecto.. ojo soy nuevo quizás la pregunta sea algo obvia para ustedes pero estoy un poco ya medio complicado con el tema

controlador:

```
detalles
class Detalle < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :encabezado , optional: true
end
encabezado
class Encabezado < ApplicationRecord
has_many :detalles
end
```

Controlador encabezado:

```
 class EncabezadosController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_encabezado, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /encabezados
  # GET /encabezados.json
 def index
 @encabezados = Encabezado.all
 end

 # GET /encabezados/1
 # GET /encabezados/1.json
 def show
 @e = nose
 end

 # GET /encabezados/new
 def new
 @encabezado = Encabezado.new
 end

 # GET /encabezados/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /encabezados
 # POST /encabezados.json
 def create
 @encabezado = Encabezado.new(encabezado_params)
 respond_to do |format|
 if @encabezado.save
 format.html { redirect_to @encabezado, notice: 'Encabezado was successfully 
 created.' }
 format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @encabezado }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @encabezado.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end

 # PATCH/PUT /encabezados/1
 # PATCH/PUT /encabezados/1.json
 def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @encabezado.update(encabezado_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @encabezado, notice: 'Encabezado was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @encabezado }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @encabezado.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

# DELETE /encabezados/1
# DELETE /encabezados/1.json
def destroy
@encabezado.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to encabezados_url, notice: 'Encabezado was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end

 private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_encabezado
   @encabezado = Encabezado.find(params[:id])
 end

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list 
 through.
 def encabezado_params
  params.require(:encabezado).permit(:numero_oc, :tipo_oc, :fecha_g, :fecha_en, :fecha_list, :d_comprador, :lugar_entrega, :emisor, :inf_comprador, :codic_pago, :diascredito, :diasentrega, :status_oc, :text)
  end



   def   nose 
   File.foreach('abc.txt').with_object([]) do |line, result|
           puts line    
        if line.start_with?('UNH')
           clave1     =  'ORDEN DE COMPRA'
        end        
        if line.start_with?('BGM')
              clave2     = line[0..2]
              @codigooc = line[6...26]  
            if line.include?('BGM2') 
               tipooc = 'ORDEN DE COMPRA '   
               cajas = line[-1]           
               else                    
               tipooc = 'ORDEN DE COMPRA SUGERIDA'
            end
             if cajas = '1'  
                @dtipooc = 'CANCELACION'
            end
            if cajas = '9'
               @dtipooc = 'ORIGINAL'                
            end
            if cajas = '6'
               @dtipooc = 'PROPUESTA'                        
            end 
        end#line GBM

      if line.start_with?('DTM137')
         fechag2 = Date.new.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
         clave     = line[0..5]
         fechag = line[6...14]
         @fechag2 = fechag
      end
      if line.start_with?('DTM ')
         fechaen2 = Date.new.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
         clave    = line[0..2]
         fechaen = line[6...14]
         @fechaen2 = fechaen            
      end
     if line.start_with?('DTM157')# 
        fechalist2 = Date.new.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        fechalist = line[6...14]
        @fechalist2 = fechalist 
     end

     if line.start_with?('NADBY')              
        clave     = line[0..4]
        @comprador = line[6...-1]#valor original 6..1 modificado por pruebebas              
     end
     if line.start_with?('NADSU')
        clave = line[0..4]
        @proveedor = line[6...-1]       
     end
     if line.start_with?('CTAOC') and line.include?('LA VINOTECA LIMITADA') or line.include?('AVDA.MANUEL MONT 1452') or line.include?('3433607')
        clave     = line[0..4]
        @emisor = "LA VINOTECA MADURO"          
     end
     if line.start_with?('CTAOC') and !line.include?('LA VINOTECA LIMITADA') and !line.include?('AVDA.MANUEL MONT 1452') and !line.include?('3433607')
        @emisor2 = line[6...-1] 
     end
     if line.start_with?('PAT')
        clave     = line[0..2]
        tpago = line[5]
        dentrega = line[7..8]
        dpagar = line [-3..-1]
        result << "#{clave} , codigo #{tpago} , condiciones normales #
 {tpago} , dias para entrega #{dentrega}  , Dias para pagar #{dpagar} "
     end
     if line.start_with?('TODNC')
        clave     = line[0..4]
        @flete1 = 'flete por cuenta del vendedor sin costo'
     else
        @flete1 = 'flete por cuenta del comprador'        
     end
     if line.start_with?('LOC')
        clave     = line[0..2]
        lugar = line[5]
        codigolugar = line[6...-1]
        @codigolugar2 = codigolugar           
     end
        #Encabezado.create( numero_oc:@codigooc , tipo_oc:@dtipooc , 
fecha_g:@fechag2 , lugar_entrega:@codigolugar2 , inf_comprador:@emisor2)


 end#do
  @p = Encabezado.new( numero_oc:@codigooc , tipo_oc:@dtipooc , 
fecha_g:@fechag2 , lugar_entrega:@codigolugar2 , inf_comprador:@emisor2 ,  
fecha_en: @fechaen2 , fecha_list: @fechalist2 , d_comprador:@comprador)
 #=   Detalle.new


   File.foreach('abc.txt').with_object([]) do |line, result|
     puts "procensando linea #{line} ..."
        case
        when line.start_with?('LIN')

            @cproducto = line[9..-2]
            @numeroitem = line[7..8]
            @numeroitem2 = @numeroitem.to_s
        when line.start_with?('IMD')
            @desproducto = line[8..-1]
        when line.start_with?('QTY 21')                      
            @cantidadpedida = line[19..20]              
            caja   = line[-3..-1]
            pedido = '?????????????????????'
            when line.start_with?('QTY129')
            @cantidadunidades = line[-6..-4]                               
            @tunidad = 'Unidades Simples'
            #Detalle.last.destroy                        
        when line.start_with?('MOA203') # not ('MOA 203') 
            @precio = 'Precio neto'
            @precioneto = line[7..-1] # not [-10..-1
            @precioneto2 = @precioneto.to_f.round(3).to_f              
#Detalle.create(cproducto: @cproducto, cantidadunidades: @cantidadunidades, 
desproducto:@desproducto,  precio: @precioneto)
        when line.start_with?('MOA 204')                
            @tdescu = 'Descuento'
            @valordescu = line[-10..-1]
        when line.start_with?('PRIAAA')
            pedido = line[-3..-1]
            @valorcd = line[-16..-8]                            
           # @tcaja2  = unitOfMeasure(pedido)
        when (line.start_with?('ALCA') and (line.include?('DE1') or 
line.include?('DE2')))
            @cdescuento = 'DESCUENTO'              
        when line.start_with?('ALCC') && (line.include?('CA1') || 
line.include?('CA1'))   

            @ccargo = 'CARGO'         
        when line.start_with?('PCD')
            if line[5] = '1'
            then
                porcentaje   = line[-6..-1] # 
                @porecentaje = 'porcentaje de descuento'
            else
                @porecentaje = 'porcentaje del cargo'
            end  
         when line.start_with?('MOA 23')
              @tcargo = 'Cargo'
              @valorcargo = line[-10..-1]

@p.detalles.create(cod_prod:@cproducto,descrip:@desproducto, 
numero_item:@numeroitem2, cantidadpedida:@cantidadpedida , precio_unit: 
@precioneto2) 

        when line.start_with?('MOA 86')

            clave   = line[0..2]              
            importe = line[-9..-1]               
        when line.start_with?('CNT')                             
            @items2 = line[-2..-1]
        else

            puts 'empieza con otra cosa'
        end

  def unitOfMeasure(p_pedido)
    case p_pedido
    when 'CS'  then 'cajas'
    when 'CSC' then 'cajas de carton'
    when 'SIN' then 'Unidades Simples'
    when 'KGM' then 'Kilogramos'
    else
        puts "bad unit #{p_pedido}"
        'undefined'
    end
  end
@p.save
end   

@p

end 
#end nose

#puts nose('ojos.txt')
end
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el controlador y acción que llaman a la vista? Seguramente no has definifo `@detalle` ahí. También serviría si agregar los modelos `Encabezado` y `Detalle` (asumo que son modelos) para ver como estableces la relación entre ellos.

Comment: Hola @gerry estaba fuera de la oficina, si tengo el método ´@detalle´ actualice mi pregunta. para que vieras el controlador y el modelo como lo tengo configurado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás definiendo la variable `@detalle` en el contolador, por lo tanto obtienes `nil` cuando quieres utilizarla.

Podrías agregarla en la acción que llama a tu vista pero, dado que tienes una relación `has_many :detalles`, podrías omitirla por completo y sustituir la variable `@detalle` en tu vista por `@encabezado.detalles`, junto con una iteración (para mostrar cada registro de `Detalle` relacionado):

```
<% @encabezado.detalles.each do |detalle| %>
<p>
  <strong>Cod prod:</strong>
  <%= detalle.cod_prod %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Numero item:</strong>
  <%= detalle.numero_item %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Descrip:</strong>
  <%= detalle.descrip %>
</p>
<% end %>
```